# c++ boost::split error, cant convert from 'initializer list' to 'SeqT'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2019

im using the boost library to split a string but I'm getting an error

`'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'SeqT'`
which is on line 29 of CmdInst.hpp (it will also have comment next to it)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CmdInst.hpp"

int main() {
    auto inst = cmd::cmdInst();
    inst.start();
}
```

CmdInst.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>


namespace cmd {
    class cmdInst {
        private:
            std::string loc;
        public:
            
            cmdInst(std::string curloc = "") {
                loc = curloc;
            }
            void start() {
                while (true) {
                    std::string cmd;
                    std::cout << "&" << loc << ">";
                    std::cin >> cmd;
                    boost::split(cmd, cmd, boost::is_any_of(" "));

                    if (std::to_string(cmd[0]) == "cd") {
                        if (std::to_string(cmd[1]) == "..") {
                            std::vector<std::string> tloc;
                             
                            boost::split(tloc,loc,boost::is_any_of("/")); //------error here------
                            std::string tmp("");

                            for (size_t i = 0; i < tloc.size() - 1; i++) {
                                tmp += tloc[i]+"/";
                            }

                            loc = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        loc += "/" + cmd[1];
                    }

                    std::cout << "\n";
                }
            }
        
    };
}
```

the error is actually coming from a boost library folder that is called from the split function but here is the line that I "actually" causing the error

```
inline SeqT copy_range( const Range& r )
{
      return SeqT( boost::begin( r ), boost::end( r ) ); //error on this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a compiler error in this line (`cmd` has the type `std::string`, so it fails to compile):

```
boost::split(cmd, cmd, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

The main change is in these two lines, I have changed the split target to `std::vector<std::string>`

```
std::vector<std::string> cmds;
boost::split(cmds, cmd, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

You have misused `std::to_string` too, so I removed the conversion. `std::to_string` is for the number to string [conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), it's not appropriate here.

```
if (cmds[0] == "cd") {
  if (cmds[1] == "..") {
  // ...
  }
}
```

I have fixed the code, it's hosted [online](https://godbolt.org/z/3dxrMj).